# wa=wsignupcleanup1.0 does not sign out user on Relying Party

Tags: c#, security, wif, claims-based-identity

Working on project where we use Windows Identity Foundation. 
While testing the sign out solution i found that the following call
http://rp/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0 does not delete the FedAuth cookie on the RP.
Which in turn make the user stay signed in at the RP.

To remedy the situation I added the following code to the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SigningOut += new EventHandler<SigningOutEventArgs>(WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SigningOut);
}

void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SigningOut(object sender, SigningOutEventArgs e)
{
    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
}
```

But shouldn't WIF take care of this automatically?
Or is this the way to do it?

Comment: It should work, particularly it works for our project. Check what is the HTTP response from your RP with Fiddler, FireBug or similar tool. And also check that you correctly activate WIF httpModules in web.config.

Comment: I used the code but I got error like `Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SigningOutEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all the url casings match, even the application name, website name casing in IIS should match the urls in configs. I had a hard time tracking this down. See here: [wasignoutcleanup issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/Geneva/thread/8274dcf1-62fc-4cd6-abe2-0b80e0f758e9)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Anton. It should work for the WIF cookies. It doesn't cleanup your ***own*** session though.

If you have additional stuff to cleanup, then you need to do additional work. The caveat is that the session object is not available from any WIF event handlers. So, for example you can't call *Session.Abandon()* from *WSFederationAuthenticationModuleSigningOut*. Typically, you redirect to another page for final cleanup. An example of this is available here: http://claimsid.codeplex.com (sample #1)